# Does anyone know who made the part that attaches the shifter to the bar?

Tags: shifter, handlebars

Looking to set something up like this with bullhorns, can't find the part to attach shifter to bar.

[image: http://imgur.com/cvWOSbS]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Those look like a pair of [Paul's Thumbies](https://paulcomp.com/shop/components/shimanothumbies/).

You can also just buy bar end shifters and attach them to the bars as well. This will likely be a lot cheaper provided the bar ends fit in the bullhorn you're using.

Comment: Correct, They are Paul Components.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I would vote you up if I could.  

I currently have bar ends on drop bars on my cross check.  I am considering switching to bullhorns with brakes on the ends of the bullhorns and the shifters near the stem.

Comment: Of note, these are 26.0mm Paul's Thumbies. Those are the only ones with the hinge on that side with approximately the correct clamp diameter. You can find a very good photo album here: imgur.com/a/CZ9zf 

Unfortunately, they no longer make the 26.0mm version, but sometimes you can find them used.

Comment: You could probably 3d print something with a few hours of work or something if you really want, I suppose. Or shimming.